# There is a semi -colon in the third quote, and the quote displays correctly, but does not tweet correctly. It truncates at the semi-colon

Tags: javascript

There is a semi -colon in the third quote, and the quote displays correctly, but does not tweet correctly.  It truncates at the semi-colon.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var randQuote;
  var randAuthor;
  var randNum;



  function getQuote(){
    var quote =["While you are destroying your mind watching the worthless,     brain-rotting drivel on TV, we on the Internet are exchanging, freely and openly, the most uninhibited, intimate and, yes, shocking details about our config.sys settings", "The secret of getting ahead is getting started.", "The unforgivable crime is soft hitting.  Do not hit at all if it can be avoided; but never hit softly.", "The man on the top of the mountain didn't fall there.", "You can avoid most of the sorrows of life, the only requirement being that you avoid all the happiness."];
    var author =["-Dave Barry", "-Mark Twain", "-Theodore Roosevelt","-Vince Lombardi", "-Robert Brault"];
 var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*quote.length);
 randQuote = quote[randNum];
 randAuthor = author[randNum];
$(".quote").text(randQuote);
$(".author").text(randAuthor);
  }

  $("#newQuote").on("click", function(){
  getQuote();    
  });


  $("#tweet").on("click", function(){
    var tweetQuote = randQuote;
    var currentLength = randQuote.length + randAuthor.length + 1;
  if(currentLength > 140){
  var oneforty = 139 - randAuthor.length ; // 140 minus the space
  tweetQuote = tweetQuote.slice(0, oneforty);
}
 window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + tweetQuote + " " +   randAuthor);
  })

});
```

Comment: you might want a encodeURIComponent() on tweetQuote and randAuthor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the query as it's going through the url.

You can use `encodeURIComponent()` or `escape()` for any variable that you're adding that might have special characters.

Your code will look like this

```
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + encodeURIComponent(tweetQuote) + " " +   encodeURIComponent(randAuthor));
```

Check this as example:

https://jsfiddle.net/nabtron/duyzk98b/2/

**Update:**

Don't use `escape()`, as it has been deprecated since ECMAScript v3.

Comment: Just don't tell about `escape` and you won't even need the disclaimer… Now that we've deprecated we must learn to forget it.

Comment: knowledge should be there :)